# Can I match a pattern in a file, make a change to it and insert the whole line somewhere else in the file?

Tags: sed, terminal

I'm trying to use **`sed`** for a repetitive task at hand. What I want to do is search a bunch of files for some pattern, make some change to it and then insert that whole line somewhere else in the same file it was found. Preferable at a specific place found by some other pattern. Without affecting the original pattern.

For simplicity's sake let's say it's a key-value store where some new key should have the same value as some other key in each file. Say each file in the directory looks something like this:

```
key10=value10
key20=value20
key30=value30
key40=value40
```

Now I want to find the `key10=value10` pattern, change `key10` to `key35` and insert it after `key30`. Using a Linux terminal. Preferably using a one-liner and for all the files in the directory at once.

```
sed -n 's/key10/key35/p' file1
```

will print what I want, i.e `key35=value10`. What I need now is to preserve this for insertion into `file1` at the line after where `key30=value30` is found.

I guess a `for file in 'ls'` could later be used to perform this operation on each file in dir. Just need the one-liner first, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cat in.txt 
key10=value10
key20=value20
key30=value30
key40=value40
$ sed "/key30=value30/a `sed -n 's/key10/key35/p' in.txt`" in.txt > out.txt; mv out.txt in.txt
$ cat in.txt 
key10=value10
key20=value20
key30=value30
key35=value10
key40=value40
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Even ran smoothly with `for file in` except for one file that had a white space in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use sed to keep the file sorted:

```
for file in *; do
   sed 's/^key10=/key35=/' "$file" | sort > tmpname && mv tmpname "$file"
done
```

Comment: I'll keep `sort` in mind. However I won't try it on my xml file this time :)